# Image not appearing on screen using Material UI + React and HOC for modularization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I'm trying to have an image displayed on my Card in Material UI but the image never shows up and I'm pretty sure the directory to the image is right. Also, if possible can anyone help me with modularizing my code because as you can see some of my code is being repeated (e.g. the box that's responsible for setting margin), I tried using HOC but I kept getting this error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import CreateIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Create";
import styled from "@material-ui/core/styles/styled";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";

const PetitionCard = (props) => {
  const { title, description, image } = props;
  const MyCard = styled(Card)({
    display: "block",
    width: "25vw",
    height: "30vw",
  });
  return (
    <Grid justify='space-evenly'>
      <MyCard>
        <Box mt={1}>
          <Grid container justify='center'>
            <TextField
              id='outlined-multiline-static'
              multiline
              rows={1}
              variant='outlined'
              placeholder='Title'
            />
          </Grid>
        </Box>

        <CardMedia
          image='./burger.jpg'
          title='Petition'
          style={{ height: 0, paddingTop: "40.25%" }}
        ></CardMedia>

        <Box mt={1} justify='center'>
          <Grid container justify='center'>
            <TextField
              size='small'
              inputProps={{
                style: { fontSize: 15 },
              }}
              id='outlined-multiline-static'
              multiline
              rows={5}
              placeholder='Description'
              variant='outlined'
            />
          </Grid>
        </Box>

        <Box mt={1}>
          <Grid container justify='center'>
            <Button>
              <CreateIcon />
              Create Petition!
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Box>
      </MyCard>
    </Grid>
  );
};

const App = () => <PetitionCard />;
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Here is my file directories

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import burger from './burger.jpg'

<CardMedia image={burger} />
```

With webpack, using static assets like images and fonts works similarly to CSS.

You can import a file right in a JavaScript module. This tells webpack to include that file in the bundle. Unlike CSS imports, importing a file gives you a string value. This value is the final path you can reference in your code, e.g. as the src attribute of an image or the href of a link to a PDF. This ensures that when the project is built, webpack will correctly move the images into the build folder, and provide us with correct paths.

If you make a typo or accidentally delete an important file, you will see a compilation error, like when you import a non-existent JavaScript module. The final filenames in the compiled bundle are generated by webpack from content hashes. If the file content changes in the future, webpack will give it a different name in production so you don’t need to worry about long-term caching of assets.

[Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/)

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.